# How to draw a Bezier curve programmatically in WPF?

Tags: wpf, bezier

I need to write a simple WPF program to draw a Bezier curve, but I have to draw it programmatically since I need to allow user to modify the shape interactively.

Any code sample to do this task is highly appreciated!

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: see https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/769055/Interpolate-D-points-usign-Bezier-curves-in-WPF there are several other bezier/wpf related projects.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Path Markup Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752293.aspx) to get a feel for the raw drawing primitives available to you in WPF.

You could use either cubic or quadratic Bezier curves (each has a smoothed version too) depending on how you want to define the control points.

As for rendering the control points on screen and allowing the user to drag them about you might like to look into adorners and possibly the Thumb class.